# I inserted data into a sql server table but the non-ascii characters are not correct

Tags: sql-server

I tried to insert this data:

```
   Insert into freqleeds (id, freq, text) values (14988,2.24,'欺瞞')
```

Into

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FreqLeeds] (
    [Id]   INT             NOT NULL,
    [Freq] DECIMAL (18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [Text] NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Is there some reason why the third column data just shows as ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use N' with your string value:

```
INSERT INTO freqleeds (id, freq, text) values (14988,2.24,N'欺瞞')
```